# Desktop crashing after going to screensaver

Tags: desktop, windows

My works domain has an automatic desktop lock after 15 minutes. It is enforced by going to screensaver and having the on resume password protect option selected.

I am unable to disable this option on the local machine, as it's enforced by GPO, and I am unable to edit the GPO as I don't have the permissions.

Whenever this laptop goes to Screensaver, when attempting to return to the desktop, the login window isn't show, however the mouse will still move. The only way we've been able to get around this is by doing a hard reset of the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the screensaver or is that set by GPO as well? Are there entries in the event log? Have you contacted your IT department and asked them to investigate the situation?

Comment: I am the IT department. I'm trying to troubleshoot this problem. I have no effing idea why it is crashing at this particular point. I didn't think to change the actual screensaver, however I don't see what that would do.

I didn't think about Event log, as this problem normally occurs while no-one is at the computer, so the exact time frame of the crash is unknown.

Comment: There still may be an event log entry for it. If you don't know the time it happens, just sort by message type and scroll through the warnings and errors. If the screen saver is corrupt then there may be a problem resuming from it, I've seen it before. Also, make sure the drivers are up to date, most specifically the chipset and video drivers.

Comment: A screensaver is a program like any other, and badly-written ones can easily crash your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if this only happens on your machine or if it also happens on others?  Also, check your drivers and ensure that they're up to date.  Depending on the screensaver being used - particularly if it's an OpenGL or Direct3D one - there may be issues there.

I'm a bit concerned about your statement that you are the IT dept but yet you don't have permissions to edit the GPO in question, by the way...

Comment: As above, I'm not THE IT department, I'm on the IT department. I'm also the junior, which is why I don't have permissions to edit alot of the more system critical components.

Answer (score 0):

I am also concerned that you are the IT department yet you didn't think to check event logs.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, that I'm not the IT department, I'm on the IT department. Event logs just slipped my mind, as I'm usually able to fix the faults before having to think about event viewer.

I should point out, I'm actually the junior member of my team, and I've only been working in this field for a year now.